# Cannot deserialize the JSON array

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have Json like below:

```
[
    {
        "name": "ts.DatumVon",
        "value": "29.10.2015"
    },
    {
        "name": "ts.Von",
        "value": "8:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "ts.Bis",
        "value": "16:30"
    }
]
```

for this class:

```
public class TSInfo
{
    public TimeSaver ts { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public TSStatus tsStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Typ")]
    public TSTyp tsTyp { get; set; }

    public TSAuswahlSteps step { get; set; }
}
```

How to deserialize this Json string in controller method?

EDIT:
I hope that clarifies it.

```
public class TimeSaver
{
    public DateTime DatumVon { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Von { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Bis { get; set; }
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
string tsi = [{"name":"ts.DatumVon","value":"29.10.2015"},{"name":"ts.Von","value":"8:00"},{"name":"ts.Bis","value":"16:30"}]
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<String,String>>(tsi);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really can't can't see how this JSON represents the class you've provided....

Comment: How do u deserialize at the moment and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you provided is a list of dictionaries. So you can deserialize it (using NewtonSoft.Json) like this:

```
string json = "your json";
var result = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<String,String>>(json);
```

How you map the result to your class is up to you.

**EDIT** the above makes no sense. Sorry for that.

Well, your JSON gave me some headache but I think I fixed it.

The JSON is an array of `KeyValuePairs`. Every pair describes an attribute of your `TimeSaver` class. The array as an whole describes the complete class. I don't know of an easy way to convert this JSON to a C# class. What complicates the problem even more is the fact that every attribute has some sort of namespace prefix: `ts`. The final complication is the date format. That's not a format that's recognized automatically.

My solution converts the JSON to a new JSON describing a `TimeSaver` object. This new JSON is then deserialized using JsonConvert.

One issue still remains: the `TimeSaver.DateVon` has become a string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string tsi = "[{\"name\":\"ts.DatumVon\",\"value\":\"29.10.2015\"},{\"name\":\"ts.Von\",\"value\":\"8:00\"},{\"name\":\"ts.Bis\",\"value\":\"16:30\"}]";

        var attributes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NameValuePair>>(tsi);
        attributes = attributes
            .Select(item => new NameValuePair { Name = item.Name.Replace("ts.", ""), Value = item.Value })
            .ToList();

        var newJson = "{" + String.Join(",", attributes.Select(item => String.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", item.Name, item.Value))) + "}";

        Console.WriteLine(newJson);

        var ts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimeSaver>(newJson);

        Console.WriteLine(ts.DatumVon);
        Console.WriteLine(ts.Von);
        Console.WriteLine(ts.Bis);
    }
}

public class NameValuePair
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class TimeSaver
{
    public String DatumVon { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Von { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Bis { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert doesn't contain "Deserialize" by itself. Do you mean "DeserializeObject"? That i've tried so far